# Heat distribution surrounding a hot piece of coal

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I apologize if this question is obvious.

I want to know if a simple model of the heat distribution for a radiating body (such as a hot piece of coal) exists? If so, could you please point me in the right direction to learn more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by heat? Temperature variations in space? Even that's ambiguous. One interpretation of the question is the air temperature. This is very difficult to answer - air is a pretty good insulator, but there's convection, so you have airflow to consider, and the transfer of heat to air is complicated on its own.

I assume you want to know how hot you would feel at some distance? That is almost exclusively related to radiative flux - so not temperature, but how much energy a unit of area receives per unit of time. That of course falls with a square of the distance from the body. The flux at the surface is determined solely from the temperature of the coal via Stefan's law.

If you leave something at some place for a long time, then its temperature will stabilize. That can actually be calculated from the principles above (if we ignore evaporative cooling, cooling with convection,...). Take a small ball put at a distance $R$ from the coal, and assume coal has radius $r$, and the ball radius $\rho$. It receives the flux from the coal, flux from the surroundings (temperature of surroundings matters) and gives away its own flux due to its temperature. When these are in balance, the temperature stabilizes.

Flux of the coal due to its temperature $T_C$: $j=\sigma T_C^4$.

Distance attenuated flux at the place of the ball: $j=\sigma T_C^4 \frac{r^2}{R^2}$.

Power received from the coal: $P_1=jS=\sigma T_C^4 \frac{r^2}{R^2}\pi \rho^2$.

Without the coal, the ball would be in radiative equilibrium with surroundings, so the ambiend flux would be equal to the flux radiated from the ball at ambient temperature $T_0$, so $P_2=\sigma T_0^4 (4\pi \rho^2)$. We ignore the fact that the coal obscures a small portion of the surroundings.

You're also losing power due to your own temperature $T$: $P_3=-\sigma T^4 (4\pi \rho^2)$.

Equilibrium condition is $P_1+P_2+P_3=0$, or:

$$\sigma T_C^4 \frac{r^2}{R^2}\pi \rho^2+\sigma T_0^4 (4\pi \rho^2)=\sigma T^4 (4\pi \rho^2)$$

$$T_C^4 \frac{r^2}{R^2}+ 4T_0^4  =4T^4 $$
$$T=\sqrt[4]{T_0^4+T_C^4\frac{r^2}{4R^2}}$$

As long as the second term is much much bigger than the first (if the coal is hot *and* you are close enough), you can ignore the ambient term, and you get
$$T\approx T_C \sqrt{r/2R}$$

This also accurately determines the average temperature of the earth based on the temperature of the sun and its distance. Or, in reverse, lets you measure the temperature of the sun simply by measuring its angular size on the sky (r/2R is a quarter of the angular diameter of the sun/coal, in radians).

Disclaimer: I assumed coal is black, which, I think, is reasonable. What's a worse assumption is, that the "ball" has a homogeneous temperature. For earth, it kind of works because it spins. For a flat surface which doesn't cool from the other side, skip the factor $4$ in the fraction, so you get

$$T\approx T_C \sqrt{r/R}$$